# Typecast to unsigned char and multiply the variables

Tags: c

```
printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)255 * (unsigned char)255);
```

The output of the code above is 65025 but not 1 (255 * 255 (mod 256)). Why?

Comment: The problem could be `(unsigned char) (255 * 255)`.

Comment: Per the C standard, unsigned integer types do not overflow but use modulo arithmetic

Comment: @iharob: What do you mean? That's a different expression?

Comment: @mpez0: True -- but there is no unsigned multiplication here.

Comment: unsigned 255 * unsigned 255 = 65025.  and the printf is using the %d format specifier, which can handle (on a 32 bit system) +- 2 gig.  so naturally the output is displaying correctly.   However, for future reference, %d is for signed integers.  You should use %u for unsigned integers (in this case, the output would be the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The multiplication operator `*` applies the *usual arithmetic conversions* to its operands. These conversions convert the `unsigned` char operands to `int`. See [pmg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30717197/827263) for the standard reference.

Apparently on your system type `int` is wide enough to hold the result value `65025`. On a system with 16-bit `int`, where `INT_MAX == 32767`, the multiplication would result in an overflow, causing undefined behavior (typically the high-order bits of the result would be discarded). Most modern systems have 32-bit `int`.

There is no multiplication operator for integer types narrower than `int` or `unsigned int`.

(Strictly speaking, it's possible that the operands could be converted to `unsigned int` rather than to `int`. That would happen only if `unsigned int` can represent the entire range of `unsigned char`, but `int` cannot -- and that cannot happen on a system with 8-bit `char`.)

Answer (score 6):

The operands to `*` undergo the ["usual arithmetic conversions"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) (C11 Standard p6.3.1.8).

Also see p6.5.5.2: [Multiplicative operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5)

> **Semantics**
>   The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

Comment: Thanks for the standard reference.